# Excel VBA: Get inner text of HTML table td

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I'm using excel to get values from a webpage. Among other elements, the HTML contains the following table:

```
<div id="myDiv">    
<table class="myTable">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to have a typo in your variable name. Have you used `Option Explicit`?

```
Function myFunction(id)
    Call myConnection(id)    
    Set myDadta = oHtml.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByClassName("myTable")(0).getElementsByClassName("data")(0)
    myFunction = myData.innerText   ' <-- This line
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

I put a Button on VBA form and the following corrected code that works:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oHtml, myData

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox myFunction(0)
End Sub

Function myFunction(id)
    Call myConnection(id)
    Set myData = oHtml.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("Table")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(1)
    myFunction = myData.innerText ' <-- will give 0.51
End Function

Public Sub myConnection(id)
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        '.Open "GET", "http://www.example.com" & id, False
        .Open "GET", "http://localhost/Test/Test.htm", False   '<-- this is my local machine; replace appropriately
        .send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

**UPDATED CODE TO DEMONSTRATE FUNCTION ON LIVE URL**

```
Option Explicit

Dim oHtml, myData

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox myFunction(0)
End Sub

Function myFunction(id)
    Call myConnection(id)
    Set myData = oHtml.getElementById("overallRatios").getElementsByTagName("Table")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(1)
    myFunction = myData.innerText  
End Function

Public Sub myConnection(id)
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        '.Open "GET", "http://www.example.com" & id, False
        .Open "GET", "http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=PTI.LS", False
        .send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot of working demo]

Comment: + 1 LOL Nice catch :)

Comment: That was just at the first glance. There are more problems with the code. Posting updates...

Comment: Sorry, it returns #VALUE! Can you get the value of the Beta of this page (1.12) http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=PTI.LS

Comment: Bingo! It works, finnally! Now the whole sheet is too slow, but that's another question, if you have any clues, I'd appreciate. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Good work pradeep :) Wish i could upvote this again. @NunoNogueira: If this is what you were looking for then accept this answer rather than mine ;)

Comment: Yes, it was an excellent work, if you don't mind, I'll accept his answer then :-D

Comment: @NunoNogueira: AFAIK Sid, he never answers questions for points. He has a pet phrase something which says that points can't buy you harley davidson. However I feel that he had answered what your actual quesiton was. My answer is just an update to your edit.
BTW avoid using `getElementsByClassName` as it won't work on all IE versions and all browsers consistantly. Or you will have to define your own javascript extension methods explicitly.

Comment: @PradeepKumar: Let's stop confusing the poor guy about what to accept and what not to :) He has made a choice which is right in my opinion and lets stick to it... Oh you remember the phrase :P

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Yes I remember it from the MVP Summit in Goa ;)

Comment: @NunoNogueira: Regarding the slowness, it is because everything is working synchronously and on single thread. Excel VBA is basically single threaded. Had it been .NET or any other language that supports multi-threading, you could have used that capability to speed it up. The best you can do is try putting `DoEvents` somewhere inside the loop to stop the UI from freezing.

Comment: On this line `.Open "GET", "the url", False`, you can pass `True` instead of `False` to make it asynchronous. But that will involve more work to make the entire thing to get working :)

Comment: Great! I'll check that. I tried to push the pages with a timestamp and the symbol to an array, so that the UDF would call a kind of "cached" pages if they existed to make things faster. The array worked fine but somehow the process of checking existing pages for every UDF request made things very complicated. I'll check if .NET may be integrated with Excel.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me. I have set reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`

BTW you are missing a `"`in `<div id=myDiv">`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim objIe As Object, xobj As HTMLDivElement

    Set objIe = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIe.Visible = True

    objIe.navigate "C:\a.htm"

    While (objIe.Busy Or objIe.READYSTATE <> 4): DoEvents: Wend

    Set xobj = objIe.document.getElementById("myDiv")
    Set xobj = xobj.getElementsByClassName("myTable").Item(0)
    Set xobj = xobj.getElementsByClassName("data")(0)

    Debug.Print xobj.innerText

    Set xobj = Nothing

    objIe.Quit
    Set objIe = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: I get Run-time error '91' Object variable or With block variable not set on line Set xobj ...

Comment: Did you set a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`?

Comment: Yes, your code is correct. I can now see, but it doesn't work for me because I established a different connection, I'll edit my question above.

Comment: Well thanks for helping anyway, I'll accept your answer since the code is good.

Comment: I hadn't seen the update. I'll check. The code in the function is opening a web connection making the application so slow I don't think it will be viable like this. Anyway, I'll give feedback, thanks!